How to keep only one composable screen in stack?
I have a composable screen for the tablet implementation, where on the left side I have a panel with a list of buttons, once a user clicks on any of these buttons it opens the related screen in the right panel.
In order to support this functionality I use NavHost in the right panel
...
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .background(Color.Cyan.copy(alpha = 0.2f)) // TODO: JUST FOR TESTING
            .fillMaxHeight()
            .weight(2f)
    ) {
        NavHost(
            navController = navController,
            startDestination = LanguageSettingsScreenRoute.ROUTE
        ) {
            composable(LanguageSettingsScreenRoute.ROUTE) {
                LanguageSettingsScreen()
            }
            composable(DeviceSettingScreenRoute.ROUTE) {
                DeviceSettingScreen()
            }
        }
    }
...

So, here I have LanguageSettingsScreenRoute as a startDestination
Then (eg:) a user clicks on the DeviceSettingScreen
...
                SettingItem.SettingType.LANGUAGE_SETTINGS ->
                    navigator.navigate(route = LanguageSettingsScreenRoute) {
                        popUpTo(LanguageSettingsScreenRoute.buildRoute()) { inclusive = true }
                    }
                SettingItem.SettingType.DEVICE_SETTINGS ->
                    navigator.navigate(route = DeviceSettingScreenRoute) {
                        popUpTo(DeviceSettingScreenRoute.buildRoute()) { inclusive = true }
                    }
...

So, I expect DeviceSettingScreen to be the only screen in the stack, however, actually, it goes on top of LanguageSettingsScreen. So, when I click back once it pops ups the second screen - DeviceSettingScreen and then it is necessary to click back again in order to pop up the first screen LanguageSettingsScreen and quit.
The question is - how to keep only one "selected" screen in the stack and remove all others, so a user clicks back once and quits.
UPD
Followed by the answer there is my impl
...
    appNavigationEventReceiver.deviceSettingsScreen = {
        navigator.navigate(route = it.buildRoute()) {
            popUpTo(navigator.graph.startDestinationId) { inclusive = true }
            launchSingleTop = true
        }
    }
...

Since I need only one screen to be on the top it is also means that it is necessary not to recompose the same screen if it is already on the top and a user tries to open it again (eg: clicks - "open screen A" button again), it is a reason I added launchSingleTop = true.
But I still see that it triggers recomposition everytime a user clicks on "open screen A" btn.
Also should be mentioned that my custom solution for now is -
...
    val navigator: NavHostController = rememberNavController()

    fun isRouteTheSameAs(route: String): Boolean {
        val curRoute: String = navigator.currentRoute.orDef()
        return curRoute.isNotEmpty() && curRoute == route
    }

    appNavigationEventReceiver.languageSettingsScreen = {
        if (!isRouteTheSameAs(route = LanguageSettingsScreenRoute.ROUTE)) {
            navigator.popBackStack()
            navigator.navigate(route = it.buildRoute()) 
        }
    }
...

So, this way I see that host keeps only one screen on the top + it doesn't recompose the same screen if it is already on the top. However, I feel like this is likely a kind of workaround I hope it is supposed to be a more straightforward approach. Does it make sense?

If you don' want the navigation features, why do you even use a NavHost in the first place? You could simply replace the entire right panel with the respective screen when any of the Buttons is pressed.

@Leviathan I need navigation as for example LanguageSettingsScreen could have another buttons which would navigate a user to the following screens. But the question is - how to pop the stack and place the "root level" selected screen on top.

I think what you've done using popUpTo is somewhat right. You can set the inclusive = true to make the entry in the stack pop.
Let me give you an example with a @Composable function
@Composable
fun MyScreen() {
    val navController = rememberNavController()

    Button(onClick = {
        navController.navigate("destinationB") {
            // Pop up to the start destination of the graph and inclusive
            popUpTo(navController.graph.startDestinationId) { inclusive = true }
        }
    }) {
        Text("Navigate to B")
    }
}

In this if you navigate to "destinationB", you first make sure, that you pop everything in the stack, till the start destination, and then the inclusive flag says that you pop the start destination as well. Once you have done that, the only item in the stack, will be the destination that you are going to navigate to. In this way, if the user presses the back button, he will quit the app, since there is nothing else left in the stack to go to
Alternative approach:
I'm suggesting this approach, if you don't have a clean graph or something
You can use a custom BackHandler in some of your screens to change the routing or maybe modify it
Recommendation
I would also recommend reading the Conditional Navigation section in the developer docs

thanks for your response. Edited my answer (UPD section) please take a look

launchSingleTop shouldn't be needed, I think

it is still recompose, I added a log on the screen impl and can see that it prints each time I click on the button

Can you try saving your state, as per this

nope, still the same... Does it work differently on your end? I just wonder if it is something wrong on my end...

It should work, maybe the recomposition is due to something else
